# Correct architecture for the raspberry pi 1

Tags: gcc, raspberry-pi

when using the -march gcc option when compiling for a raspberry pi 1, what is the correct architecture to use? I've seen armv6, armv6h, and armv6l and am not sure which one is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am copying this from the raspberry pi stackexchange, in case the raspberry pi stack exchange disappears. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2046/which-cpu-flags-are-suitable-for-gcc-on-raspberry-pi

"The RPI ARM core is an ARM 1176jzf-S, the suitable flags should then be

-march=armv6zk -mcpu=arm1176jzf-s -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp
Drop the -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp when on a soft float distro.

These flags can be found by running gcc -mcpu=native -march=native -Q --help=target on gcc >= 4.7`"

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to command line on your r. pi you can check architecture with commands

> uname -a

or

> cat /proc/cpuinfo

If you have any source of documentation supplied with r. pi - you might look through it or post it here so ppl can look through it.